# Numerical solution to a system of equations

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, gamma-distribution

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $u_1,u_2,\ldots ,u_n,t_1,t_2\geq 0$ be constants. I'm interested in finding the numerical solution in relation to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to the following system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{u_i}{\beta}\right)^\alpha=t_1\\
\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left[ \left( \frac{u_i}{\beta}\right)^\alpha\right]=t_2
\end{cases}.$$
My current solution is to extract $\beta$ from the second equation, insert it into the first and find the solution $\alpha$ with the halving algorithm. We get
$$\begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( u_i/\exp\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n\ln u_i-\frac{t_2}{n\alpha}\right)\right)^\alpha=t_1\\ \beta = \exp\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n\ln u_i-\frac{t_2}{n\alpha}\right)\end{cases}.$$
For values 
$$u_1=1.20167063$$
$$u_2=2.30434494$$
$$u_3=1.20587080$$
$$u_4=0.59277441$$
$$u_5=0.06592318$$
$$t_1=12.5$$
$$t_2=37.5$$
The solution is $\alpha\approx 10^{-4}$ and $\beta \approx \exp(10^4)$. Any ideas on how I can avoid $\beta$ blowing up?

Comment: What is wrong with "$\beta$ blowing up" ?

Comment: The obvious reason is that using numbers of that magnitude is not practical in a programming language like R.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you say. You provide an equation and don't want to accept its solution value ?! By the way, $10^4$ is not a large number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reduction the system is equivalent to

$$
\frac{t_2}{\alpha}+5\ln \beta =\sum_{k=1}^5\ln u_k\\
\alpha\ln \beta -\ln\left(\sum_{k=1}^5 u_k^{\alpha}\right)=-\ln t_1
$$

and after the ellimination of $\ln \beta$

$$
\frac {\alpha}{5}\sum_{k=1}^5\ln u_k-t_2 = \ln\left(\sum_{k=1}^5 u_k^{\alpha}\right)-\ln t_1
$$

calling

$$
f(\alpha) = \frac {\alpha}{5}\sum_{k=1}^5\ln u_k-t_2 -\left( \ln\left(\sum_{k=1}^5 u_k^{\alpha}\right)-\ln t_1\right)
$$

at a solution $f(\alpha)$ must cross the horizontal axis. Calculating the stationary points to $f(\alpha)$ or $f'(\alpha) = 0$ we can easily verify that $\alpha = 0$ is the solution but $f(0) = -36.5837$ hence the former system doesn't have real solution.

Attached the plot for $f(\alpha)$

[image]

Note the two asymptotes given by

$$
a_1(\alpha) = \frac {\alpha}{5}\sum_{k=1}^5\ln u_k-t_2 - \alpha\ln\left(\min (u_k)\right)+\ln t_1\\
a_2(\alpha) = \frac {\alpha}{5}\sum_{k=1}^5\ln u_k-t_2 - \alpha\ln\left(\max (u_k)\right)+\ln t_1
$$